# How to run same cmd code across multiple folders

Tags: windows-10, video, cmd.exe, automation, video-conversion

I'm trying to run same cmd code across multiple folders:

```all-bat
ffmpeg -i "00.mkv" -codec copy "00.mp4"
```

So i have few folders that have `.mkv` and would like to convert them into mp4 but still keep them in their own folder.

I already renamed them into same names thinking it would help but is there anything else i should try to make the process work?

Or is there any other options other than cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Or is there any other options other than cmd?*

You can do it in cmd!

---

```bash
@echo off && cd /d "%~dpn0" 

set "_ffmpeg=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_ffmpeg=2^>^&1 "%_ffmpeg%" -hide_banner -nostats -y -i"

for /r %%i in (*.mkv)do %_ffmpeg% "%%~fi" -codec copy "%%~dpni.mp4"
```

---

Answer (score 1):

though your question is incomplete with an example, I think i might help

You can use python to automate this task

```python
import glob
all_folders = glob.glob("*")

OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "converted"
INPUT_FILE_EXTENSION_ = ".mkv"
OUTPUT_FILE_EXTENSION = ".mp4"

for folder_name in folder_names:

    out_path = pathlib.Path(folder_name) / OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME
    out_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    print(list(pathlib.Path(folder_name).glob(f"*{INPUT_FILE_EXTENSION}")))

    for file in pathlib.Path(folder_name).glob(f"*{INPUT_FILE_EXTENSION}"):

        out_file = pathlib.Path(out_path) / pathlib.Path(file.stem + file.suffix.replace(INPUT_FILE_EXTENSION, OUTPUT_FILE_EXTENSION))
        if not out_file.exists():
            print(f"Processing: {file}")
            os.system(f"ffmpeg -i \"{file}\" -coded copy \"{out_file}\"")

            print(f"Outputed {out_file}")
        else:
            print(f"Skipping {file}...")
```

be sure to save this script as `batch_ffmpeg_converter.py` (or just anything you wish to) in the same directory inc which all the folders are, and that directory contains only folders (no files) and run it using

```
python batch_ffmpeg_converter.py
```