# How to Rename Multiple Files at Once in Windows

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, automation, rename, file-extension

So i'm trying to rename few videos in separate folders to same name
and i did it without using cmd, so i just used the search box on the right side

[image]

And searched to as mp4 files and named them to "00" but all files end up as "00 (1)".

[image]

Is there anyway i can remove the (1) from the name titles or other way using cmd to rename multiple files (with same extension) to same name across folders.
i would like the videos to remain their own separate folders with renamed name only.

Comment: If you are doing this only for the purpose you describe in https://superuser.com/questions/1801321/how-to-run-same-cmd-code-across-multiple-folders, that is totally not needed! So you can just stop doing this

Comment: thanks for the reply! I think i might figure it out with the other post! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

```bash
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" 

for /r %%i in (*.mkv)do ren "%%~fi" "%%~dpi00%%~xi"
```

---

- In your **[commandline](/questions/tagged/commandline)**

```bash
for /r %i in (*.mkv)do ren "%~fi" "%~dpi00%~xi"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`CD /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

  - [`CD /d "%~dp0"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309941/what-does-it-mean-by-command-cd-d-dp0-in-windows/18310141#18310141)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)
- [`For /R /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)

  - [`For /R commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`Rename /?` | `Ren /?`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)